# Sharing OpenGL objects between contexts on Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, glx

To share OpenGL objects between different contexts (presumably running in different threads) we use wglShareLists() on Windows.How is it done for Linux?Has glx an API  to do this kind of things?

Answer (score 5):

To do this in GLX, you would pass a handle to the context you want to share resources with in your call to [`glXCreateContext (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXCreateContext.xml) or [`glXCreateNewContext (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXCreateNewContext.xml). It is really that simple, instead of having a special API function for this purpose in GLX, it's built-in to the function you use to create a context.

Comment: For real? Didn't realize it is that simple!

Comment: Yeah, ignore the part in that manual page for `glXCreateNewContext (...)` where they duplicate the word `share_list` when it should say `direct`. Countless bug reports later, it is clear nobody cares about the accuracy of the GLX specification :P

Comment: Well,this is really late )) But neither of the above mentioned methods works for modern OpenGL. glXCreateContextAttribsARB does